# How to append an hyperlink at the end of an existing text in a textbox

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to construct an anchor link based upon the text and url entered by the user and append it at the end of an existing text in a textbox. The following is my code. Nothing is added to the existing text in the txtDescription textbox. However, if I add the same link to a div, then it correctly appends the link to the div.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

   <head>
      <title>Test Page</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <script type = "text/JavaScript">
        function addLink(){
         var link = $('<a>',
                {
                    text: $('#txtDisplayText').val(),
                    title: '',
                    href: $('#txtURL').val(),
                    target: "_blank"
                }).prop('outerHTML');
            $('#txtDescription').append(link);
    }
      </script>
         <input type="text" class="k-textbox" id="txtDescription" />
     <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Display Text</label>
                <br />
                <input type='text' id="txtDisplayText"  style="width: 100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2  columnSizeDouble">
                <label>URL</label>
                <br />
                <input type='text' id="txtURL"  style="width: 100%" />
            </div>
       <button id="btnAddLink" type="button" onclick="javascript:addLink();" class="buttonStyle" 
       >Add Link</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    
   </html>
```

Comment: `<input>` elements do not have children (they're self-closing). You also cannot insert other elements into their `value` properties. It's unclear what you want the result of this to be

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced var link into var $link. Also replaced $('#txtDescription').append(link); into $('#txtDescription').val($link);